# App Crashes When Playing A Sound

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am using the `AVFoundation framework` to play a sound. At the beginning of the file, I have:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
```

And the `AVFoundation framework` is properly added to my project. However, when I use this code to play a sound, the app crashes:

```
NSString *pathForBgMusicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClenchedTeeth" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *bgMusicFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pathForBgMusicFile];
AVAudioPlayer *bgMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:bgMusicFile error:NULL];
[bgMusic play];
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your app do anything else?  If you make a dummy app with just this, does it crash? ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: above code seems to be alight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up the `AVAudioSession` as well before you attempt playback. Like this:

```
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  audioSession.delegate = self;
  [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Remember to import it, and make sure your class implements both `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` and `AVAudioSessionDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

and on your.m file

```
FBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLref;
        soundFileURLref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle ,(CFStringRef)@"yourSoundFile",CFSTR ("wav"),NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLref, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);}
```

you can use this code inside of a button if is that your case. don't forget to add the Audio tools framework. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my mac, try this (I only changed the second line):

```
NSString *pathForBgMusicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClenchedTeeth" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *bgMusicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForBgMusicFile];
AVAudioPlayer *bgMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:bgMusicFile error:NULL];
[bgMusic play];
```

Comment: If this does not help, could be useful if you give the exact line where app crashes

Comment: The [bgMusic play]; line is what crashes. Here's the crash log:

Comment: 2012-05-22 15:51:27.552 Macbeth[67496:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Comment: Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-05-22 15:51:27.558 Macbeth[67496:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262):

Comment: This is a simulator error, ignore it. Once you deploy on a device it won't show up.

Comment: Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
(lldb)